AWS API Gateway removing "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" from .NET generated response header
I have a .NET Core 6.0 AWS Lambda endpoint. I can see via the CloudWatch logs that it's returning "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the response when I serialize the response before it gets returned to the client; e.g.:
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "content-Type": "application/json",
        "cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "expires": "0",
        "access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
        "access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization"
    },
    "multiValueHeaders": null,
    "body": "{\"version\":\"1.0.0\"}",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}

But when I invoke the API endpoint from CURL or Postman, the "Access-Control-..." headers are not reflected in the response. All the other headers are being included per design.
For testing purposes, I've gone as far to set the CORS for the API Gateway CorsConfiguration to be the following:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *

(I'll lock these down further, but I'm just trying to get it working at all.)
What could possibly be stripping out the "Access-Control-..." headers from the response on its way to the client?

Some useful info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html
This makes it clear that If you configure CORS for an API, API Gateway ignores CORS headers returned from your backend integration. Looks like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html might provide answer details. I'll respond again if I get it working.

OK, I got it working; here are the steps I took:

Cleared CORS being configured at the API Gateway level.
Added an "OptionsEvent" for each API endpoint in my AWS SAM; e.g.:
 OptionsEvent:
    Type: HttpApi
    Properties:
    ApiId: !Ref NAME_OF_HTTP_API
    Path: /UNIQUE_API_ENDPOINT_PATH
    Method: OPTIONS


Had API explicitly return Access-Control header values; e.g.:
public static APIGatewayProxyResponse CreateResponse<TModel>(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, TModel model) {
    return new APIGatewayProxyResponse {
        StatusCode = (int) httpStatusCode,
        Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model),
        Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            {"Content-Type", "application/json"},

            // Discourage browsers from caching any results; relevant to GET requests
            {"Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"},
            {"Pragma", "no-cache"},
            {"Expires", "0"},

            {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"},
            {"Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"},
            {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization"}
        }
    };
}



